# how to write conditional .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

My Site's every pages has Different URL with **Seo** variable, on page click URL becomes

```
index.php?seo=home
rates.php?seo=rates
reservation.php?seo=reservation
```

now i want to convert the URL to this

```
agnow.us/rates
agnow.us/information
agnow.us/reservation
```

Here is my .htaccess file.

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+rates\.php\?seo=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ rates.php?seo=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+rates\.php\?seo=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ rates.php?seo=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: rates.php?seo=rates is changed to http://agnow.us/rates ,this page is fine but how the oyher pages will work when i Clicked on reservation.php?seo=reservation the URL remains same

Comment: Hmm now problem starts. e.g. a path like `/foobar` can be either routed to `rates.php` or `reservation.php` but no both. As a possible solution your pretty URL schemes can be `/rates/blabla` or `/reservation/blabla`. Let me know if you are fine with this proposal and I will update the answer.

Comment: is it possible to change 
agnow.us/pages/rates
agnow.us/pages/reservation

Comment: Keeping same prefix `/pages` will also not solve the problem since URL `/pages/foobar` won't tell us whether `rates.php` should be invoked or the any other php